# Translation conflict between bundles in Symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I created a Symfony application & i'm using translation for texts in my application.
The translation in one of my bundles overrides all of other bundles while translation is bundle specific & I'm not using the `app` level !
for example I have these two bundles named `MessagingBundle` & `CongratBundle` & the `Title` key is defined in both of them like this:

`src/ITW/CongratBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml:`

```
...
Title: Congrat Title 
...
```

`src/ITW/MessagingBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml:`

```
...
Title: Message Title 
...
```

Nevertheless in both `MessagingBundle` & `CongratBundle` I'm getting `Congrat Title` when I use `{{ "Title"|trans }}` !!

I'm using `Symfony 2.5.6`
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations):

> Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following
>   locations:
>
> the app/Resources/translations directory;
>
> the app/Resources//translations directory;
>
> the Resources/translations/ directory inside of **any** bundle.
>
> The locations are listed here with the highest priority first. That
>   is, you can override the translation messages of a bundle in any of
>   the top 2 directories.

I think the important part here is the **any bundle** of option three. Looks like Symfony is getting the translation from the first bundle (one of the two).

I would try this:

- Get rid of translations directory within bundles.
- Create `app/Resources/CongratBundle/translations` directory and add its `messages.en.yml`
- Create `app/Resources/MessagingBundle/translations` directory and add its `messages.en.yml`

**Important**: don't forget to clear the cache even if you're in dev environment:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Hope this solves the problem.